# Hot to change how prettier formats html tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I started using prettier for formatting my html code. I really like how it formats it, but I have 1 tiny problem in how it closes a html tag.

current formatting

```html
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
  aria-controls="navbarNav"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
```

i would love it if it formatted like this

```html
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
  aria-controls="navbarNav"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

For those who don't immediately notice, it bugs me how `>` takes an entire line instead of just being right after the last property

Any help in solving this formatting issue would be really appreciated

Comment: Searching for the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No you are the only comment  in a month this post has been here

Comment: I solved it by doing without prettier and using ESLint instead. Here is a description of my configuration: https://gist.github.com/alexandervu/e8d46daf3e7d6560542448ff03f11d7c